# How to calculate right transformation to create cut off the corner on the div in certain angle using CSS

Tags: css, algorithm, css-transforms, clipping

I want to create effect of page corner cliping like in [turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com/samples/magazine/#page/8), I know that I need two divs the outside one need to have positive rotation and inside one need the same amount but negative, and both need translate, but I don't know how to calculate the right values.

How can I do this for each corner?

Here is [my try](http://dabblet.com/gist/6068541).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try, for a cut-off of 20px:

```
.page-wrapper {
    position: absolute; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    width: 400px; 
    height: 300px; 
    top: 50px; 
    left: 50px; 
    right: auto; 
    z-index: 12;
    background-color: blue;
}
.outter-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;  
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%; 
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px) rotate(45deg);
    right: 0px;
    bottom: -100%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
}
.inner-wrapper {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(20px);
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
```

You need to make the outter wrapper bigger than the inner wrapper; if not you are clipping in places that you didn't intended. I have done it 20%%; this way the math is easier.

Also, you need to adjust it carefully so that you still know the coordinates of the transform origin.

And you don't really need to move it in x and y, it's enough to mevo it horizontally.

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/qQRHZ/)